# Python with Google App Engine. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler' error message

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I’m new to Python and I’m currently following  the Head First Python book. I’m trying to put an example exercise to work but I’m stuck with an error from the GAE. 
I installed both Python 2.5 and GAE on my Kubuntu 10.10 S.O.

First I create a folder named “mygaetest” with the files sayhello.py and app.yaml inside. 
Because there is no graphical front end for Linux, I start my GAE webapp from the command line this way:

> python2.5
>   google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
>   home/lucas/workspace/Python/Chapter10/src/mygaetest/

But then the following error is shown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 78, in
>
> ```
> run_file(__file__, globals())
> ```
>
> File
>   "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 74, in run_file
>
> ```
> execfile(script_path, globals_)
> ```
>
> File
>   "/home/lucas/Desarrollo/Python/App
>
> Engine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py",
>   line 118, in
>
> ```
> from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
> ```
>
> File
>   "/home/lucas/Desarrollo/Python/App
>
> Engine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py",
>   line 68, in
>
> ```
> from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc
> ```
>
> File
>   "/home/lucas/Desarrollo/Python/App
>
> Engine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py",
>   line 27, in
>
> ```
> import fancy_urllib
> ```
>
> File
>   "/home/lucas/Desarrollo/Python/App
>
> Engine/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/**init**.py",
>   line 341, in
>
> ```
> class FancyHTTPSHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no
>   attribute 'HTTPSHandler'

Can someone tell me what to do in order to solve that error?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Python, App Engine, and Stack Overflow!

Your Python installation apparently lacks SSL support. To add support, [install this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl).

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=19

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I’m also new to Linux. So I don’t know how to install the file I downloaded from the address you gave me.
The file is “ssl-1.15.tar.gz”, so I did  tar xvfz ssl-1.15.tar.gz and the file was uncompressed. What should I do now? I did python2.5 setup.py build but I really don’t know if that was correct, I get the follow error:
Exception: No SSL support found
Thanks again =)

Comment: It may be easier to just use Python 2.6 or 2.7, whatever came standard with your distro. Either one will mostly work fine with App Engine.

Comment: thanks again. I have Python 2.6. But when I do this: python2.6 google_appengine/dev_appserver.py home/lucas/workspace/Python/Chapter10/src/mygaetest/



I get this:
File "/home/lucas/Desarrollo/Python/App Engine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4166, in LoadAppConfig
    raise AppConfigNotFoundError
google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError
I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: That's progress. That error means that you're not pointing to a path that contains an app.yaml. Try using an absolute path, i.e. "/home" instead of "home".

Comment: Do pip install ssl gives the same error on osx with pyenv

Comment: Trying to install that gives the error: "This extension should not be used with Python 2.6 or later".

Answer (score 0):

I received this error after upgrading Mac OSX to 10.10 (Yosemite), I needed the new build of python `2.7`:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade python
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
python 2.7.8_2
==> Upgrading python
...
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2: 4777 files, 76M
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Python 2.7 and I used the following instructions to solve the problem:
http://paltman.com/2007/11/15/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251/

Comment: Page not found 6 years later.